# How to set AWS-S3 uploaded image as feature image of WordPress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, post, amazon-s3

Can anyone tell me how Can I set the S3 bucket's Image as a feature image of the WordPres post?
Here is my code sample,

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'My-Key',
        'secret' => 'My-Secret',
    ],
]);
try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3Client-> putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => 'cdn.myWeb.com',
        'Key' => 'sunburst.png',
        'Body' => fopen($image_url, 'r+'),
        'ACL' => 'public-read'
    ));
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $lastInsertedId = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, 
    $result['ObjectURL'], $post_id);
    if($lastInsertedId){
        require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $res2 = set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $lastInsertedId);
        $featureImageAdded = true;        
    }

} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

I want to set $result['ObjectURL'] as my post featur image.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below hook,

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 5 );

function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {

  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $base_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'];

  // Change the default upload directory to AWS Bucket link
  $AWSBucket = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket';
  $html = str_replace($base_url, $AWSBucket, $html);

  return $html;
}
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/modify-featured-image-path-to-amazon-s3